# How to extract specific residual data from a linear model in R

Tags: r, dplyr, broom

How would i extract extract residual data for a specific baseball team in the following linear model?  For example, how would I extract the residuals for "CLE"?

```
library(Lahman)
library(dplyr)
library(broom)

# create baseball team data
data(Teams)
teams <- Teams
teams <- teams %>% mutate(win_percentage = (W / (W + L)) * 100)

# summarize baseball team salary by year
salaries <- Salaries
salaries <- salaries %>% 
  group_by(teamID, yearID, lgID) %>%
  summarise(payroll_M = sum(as.numeric(salary)) / 10^6) %>% 
  ungroup()

# add winning percentage to the salary table
salaries <- teams %>% 
  select(yearID, teamID, win_percentage) %>% 
  right_join(salaries, by = c("yearID", "teamID"))

# compute linear model of winning vs team salary
model <- salaries %>% 
  group_by(yearID) %>%
  do(fit = augment(lm(win_percentage ~ payroll_M, data = .)))

# extract residuals for Cleveland ??????
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close, but need two changes to the `augment` line.

1. You're saving the resulting (augmented) data frame to a column called `fit`. Instead, try giving it directly to `do` (remove the `fit =`).
2. The augment function needs to keep the `teamID` column as part of the resulting data, even though it's not in the model. Note that `augment` takes a second argument `data` for exactly this purpose (see `help(augment.lm)` for more).

Thus, the new line would look like:

```
do(augment(lm(win_percentage ~ payroll_M, data = .), data = .))
```

The resulting data frame will have one row per original observation, and will include the `teamID` along with the residuals and fitted values (which allows you to filter for `CLE`).

Comment: David, thank you very much!  I did read the help for augment.lm but it was not apparent to me that the 2nd parameter was what I needed.  I'm still learning how to read and understand the help system.

Comment: David, I have a follow up for you.  The help for the "data" parameter says "Original data, defaults to the extracting it from the model".  Is all of the data that was included in the payroll data frame written to the linear model in the lm command and is augment just extracting it out of the linear model?  Am I understanding this correct?

Comment: @user3457456 by default, the data stored in the model is only the columns that were directly used in the model (try `model.frame(fit)` on a linear fit object and you'll see it). That's how the win_percentage and salary variables stuck around originally. The advantage of giving `data = .` is that it gives all of the original data to augment

Comment: Can you explain the meaning of the newdata paramter in the augment function.  I'm a little confused about that after reading the help file.  Is the newdata parameter used to estimate how the newdata would fit to a pre-computed linear model x?